# Why can't I use a DSC resource in push mode from a module that is installed in my user's module path?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have a Powershell DSC custom resource, embedded in a module. The full code is [available here](https://github.com/mrled/wintriallab/tree/e77767162df45224bbdd043b63e6c7b99886dffd/azure/DscResources/cWinTrialLab) if you want to see it, but that may not be necessary; my problem isn't (I think) in the code I wrote, but in how to access it.

In my case, I'm using DSC Push Mode. There's a normal Powershell script I use to install required modules, compile the configuration, and start it. In that script, I add the location of my module to `$env:PSModulePath`. After doing that, I can then see the module and import it in my interactive shell like this:

```
PS> Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object -Property Name -eq cWinTrialLab | Import-Module
PS> Get-DscResource -Module cWinTrialLab

ImplementedAs   Name                      ModuleName                     Version    Properties
-------------   ----                      ----------                     -------    ----------
PowerShell      cWtlShortcut              cWinTrialLab                   0.0.1      {Ensure, ShortcutPath, TargetPath, DependsOn...}
```

So I create a test configuration file:

```
Configuration TestConfig {

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName cWinTrialLab

    Node localhost {

        cWtlShortcut "TestShortcut" {
            Ensure = "Present"
            ShortcutPath = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\TestShortcut.lnk"
            TargetPath = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
        }

    }
}
```

And I try to use it:

```
PS> . .\testDscConfig.ps1
PS> TestConfig
PS> Start-DscConfiguration -Wait -Force TestConfig
```

Compiling the MOF appears to work, but actually starting the configuration fails with:

```
The PowerShell DSC resource cWtlShortcut from module <cWinTrialLab,0.0.1> does not exist at the PowerShell module path nor is it registered as a WMI DSC resource.
At $Home\Documents\psyops\submod\wintriallab\azure\test.ps1:13 char:1
+ Start-DscConfiguration -Wait -Force TestConfig
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DscResourceNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

What could cause this?

1. I have made sure that there is only *one* copy of the module in all folders in my `$env:PSModulePath`.
2. Something appears to be working; it can determine the correct version of my module in the error message (and when I change the version on my module's `.psd1` file, the version reported in the error message changes as well)
3. I don't believe it's related to [Why can't DSC find a resource that's installed?](https://serverfault.com/questions/780601/why-cant-dsc-find-a-resource-thats-installed) because I'm using push mode, and there are no module versioning issues.
4. Could it be related to a nonstandard entry in `$env:PSModulePath`? I've tried copying the module to `$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowershell\Modules`, but then I get an error I *really* don't understand:
   `Importing module cWinTrialLab failed with error - File C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\cWinTrialLab\cWtlShortcut\cWtlShortcut.psm1 cannot be loaded because
   running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies`. For the record:

   ```
   PS> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
           Scope ExecutionPolicy
           ----- ---------------
   MachinePolicy       Undefined
      UserPolicy       Undefined
         Process       Undefined
     CurrentUser    Unrestricted
    LocalMachine    Unrestricted
   ```
5. Maybe it's something wrong with my directory layout? I haven't actually seen an example of a module containing multiple class-based DSC resources in the wild, so I'm kind of guessing as to the layout.
6. (If there is an example of this kind of module - a single module, containing multiple class-based DSC resources - a link to it would be really helpful.)

Finally, I'm using Powershell 5.1 on Windows 10 with all updates applied from Windows Update. (Ultimately, I'll be deploying my configuration on a Server 2016 machine.)

What else could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing the DSC configuration runs under a system account, and therefore isn't searching a particular user's PSModulePath.  Put the module in one of the standard locations, typically under `$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

When you say you modified your `$env:PSModulePath`, I assume you did that for your current user, rather than modifying a machine wide setting.

If you need the resource to have access to resources available to a particular user, some will allow passing credential objects as parameters to the resource.

Comment: Passing credentials to a resource has some other challenges, particularly with Partial Configurations where some configurations take credentials and some do not.  If you need to go there, drop a comment here and we can start another Question.

Comment: I don't need to pass credentials for my current use case, but thanks for the offer. I will say that I had to change my module from the version that is still linked in the question - rather than a parent `cWinTrialLab` module that contains a `cWtlShortcut` child module that exports an eponymous DSC resource, I had to add the `cWtlShortcut` module itself to a directory in `$env:PSModulePath`. Once I followed your advice to use the standard location, and ditched the parent module, everything worked as expected. Thanks for your help!